# Displaying info an array of arrays from an API as a table

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to convert the result I get from an api request, which looks something like this(an array of arrays) into a table:

request result:

```
[(
    "LEC 001",
    "10:00",
    "11:20",
    PHY,
    150,
    "Tompkins,Dave"
), (
    "LEC 002",
    "10:00",
    "11:20",
    PHY,
    235,
    "Holtby,Daniel James"
), (
    "LEC 003",
    "11:30",
    "12:50",
    MC,
    4045,
    "Akinyemi,John Akinlabi"
), (
    "LEC 004",
    "11:30",
    "12:50",
    MC,
    2038,
    "Roegiest,Adam Micheal"
), (
    "LEC 005",
    "13:00",
    "14:20",
    RCH,
    307,
    "Tompkins,Dave"
), (
    "LEC 006",
    "13:00",
    "14:20",
    DWE,
    3522,
    "Istead,Lesley Ann"
), (
    "LEC 007",
    "14:30",
    "15:50",
    DWE,
    3522,
    "Istead,Lesley Ann"
), (
    "LEC 008",
    "14:30",
    "15:50",
    MC,
    1056,
    "Holtby,Daniel James"
), (
    "LEC 009",
    "16:00",
    "17:20",
    MC,
    2034,
    "Akinyemi,John Akinlabi"
), (
    "LEC 010",
    "16:00",
    "17:20",
    MC,
    2035,
    "Roegiest,Adam Micheal"
), (
    "LEC 011",
    "08:30",
    "09:50",
    MC,
    4020,
    "Heinle,Albert"
)]
```

This is how I imagine the table to look like

[image: Image description]

Comment: can you clear what you are trying to convert?

Comment: @O-mkar am sorry i mistyped it at first

Comment: What is the issue you are encountering by doing so? Do you just not know how to do it? Or is there a specific issue?

Comment: dude you have not mention what you want to do?

Comment: yeah, I am not sure how to start doing it. I would love to know the steps to code that design.

Comment: print(array[0]) //position to be displayed

Comment: be more specific what you want to do

Comment: @O-mkar Alright basically all I wanna know is, how to convert an array of strings into a table like the one i showed in the picture.

Comment: Do you want to display that data in table view?

Comment: yes thats what am trying to do

Comment: You hardly expect us to write your code. What -specific- question do you have about this? E.g. what have you tried so far and where does the roblem come up? Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) First i parsed your data it was in tuple

You can Refer this article if you want to know more how to get value from tuple
http://www.codingexplorer.com/tuples-in-swift-create-read-and-return/

Here is the output

[image: PlayGround output]

> 2) i implemented in the table view

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  test tableview
//
//  Created by O-mkar on 30/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 test. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let testArray = [(
        "LEC 001",
        "10:00",
        "11:20",
        "PHY,150",
        "Tompkins,Dave"
        ), (
            "LEC 002",
            "10:00",
            "11:20",
            "PHY,235",
            "Holtby,Daniel James"
        ), (
            "LEC 003",
            "11:30",
            "12:50",
            "MC,4045",
            "Akinyemi,John Akinlabi"
        ), (
            "LEC 004",
            "11:30",
            "12:50",
            "MC,2038",
            "Roegiest,Adam Micheal"
        ), (
            "LEC 005",
            "13:00",
            "14:20",
            "RCH,307",
            "Tompkins,Dave"
        ), (
            "LEC 006",
            "13:00",
            "14:20",
            "DWE,3522",
            "Istead,Lesley Ann"
        ), (
            "LEC 007",
            "14:30",
            "15:50",
            "DWE,3522",
            "Istead,Lesley Ann"
        ), (
            "LEC 008",
            "14:30",
            "15:50",
            "MC,1056",
            "Holtby,Daniel James"
        ), (
            "LEC 009",
            "16:00",
            "17:20",
            "MC,2034",
            "Akinyemi,John Akinlabi"
        ), (
            "LEC 010",
            "16:00",
            "17:20",
            "MC,2035",
            "Roegiest,Adam Micheal"
        ), (
            "LEC 011",
            "08:30",
            "09:50",
            "MC,4020",
            "Heinle,Albert"
        )]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return testArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let myCell:UITableViewCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototype", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        myCell.textLabel?.text = "\(testArray[indexPath.row].0) | \(testArray[indexPath.row].1) | \(testArray[indexPath.row].2) | \(testArray[indexPath.row].3) | \(testArray[indexPath.row].4) "

        return myCell

        //END ADDING ICONS
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

        return "SEC | Starts | Ends | Building | Inst "

    }



}
```

> OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

**Here is my project link you can play with it and test it and customize how you want**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2csGr9uKp1DMWRhSjlCTWdFUEU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Just one approach of many:

In Swift there's a `flatten` method defined for arrays. `flatten` "flattens" an array of arrays into an array:

```
let aa = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

aa.flatten().forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```